# Why don't *small* electric cars use small cheap hobby motors?

Tags: power, dc-motor, automotive, torque, rpm

The automotive blogger Jason Torchinsky recently bought an inexpensive electric car, a [Changli Nemeca](https://jalopnik.com/tag/changli), whose motor he describes as being powered by five car batteries and producing 1.1 horsepower (820 watts). He says it's like what you'd find in a washing machine, although it's DC not 120 V AC.  It's about as big as a 1 quart food container.  Online, similar motors cost about USD 100.

(Yes, this is much smaller than what's in a Tesla or Volt or Leaf.)

But motors of the same power (output watts, not "kV") for [hobby](https://www.banggood.com/Racerstar-RC-Brushless-Motor-BR4250-800KV-3S-7S-Support-11+5_5-Prop-for-Fixed-Wing-RC-Airplane-Drone-p-1646528.html) radio-control cars and aircraft are about **a quarter the cost**, and a quarter the linear size (so 1/64th the volume and mass).

What theoretical or practical concerns stop such smaller cheaper motors from being used in larger applications like golf carts and household appliances?  Power is power;  something like a belt drive can trade off speed against torque.

Comment: Uhm reliability, efficiency, **guaranteed specifications**, basically **quality**. If car manufacturers would do as you suggest then they can just sit and wait for the motors to fail, wait for the claims from angry customers and maybe even lawsuits for delivering inferior quality and potentially dangerous cars. You can imagine what that will do to the name of such a company. They will be out of business in no time. You obviously never dealt with the automotive industry because even the resistors they use have to be "automotive level quality".

Comment: It's like comparing apples to pears - those Motors hale totally different power level. 800KV doesn't mean 800W

Comment: The Nissan Leaf, for example, has an 80 kW motor - 100 times what you are proposing. Your 800 W motor will be equivalent to a few people pedaling the car (about 150 W each continuous over an hour or more). The Flintstones were able to go quite quickly though.

Comment: You're getting a lot of responses which miss the most essential point: the motors you are looking at *cannot* do the jobs you are asking about.  There are also reasons why something like a direct drive washing machine is considered a design feature people are willing to pay for.

Comment: Small motors are often specified for 25% duty cycle, with maximum power feasible only for a minute or so. After that, they have to cool down. Uh, and all that heat is wasted.

Comment: I think you are wrong. A hobby motor that can put out 820 Watts will be more expensive than a low-cost brushed DC motor that can put out 820 Watts. If you find the lowest cost supplier for both options. Also, the controller for the brushed motor is probably cheaper too. Hobby motors are often not rated at continuous power output. And since many of them are for driving propellers, there may be an assumption built in that extensive airflow is present. Without that airflow they may overheat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Online, similar motors cost about USD 100.

But a car manufacturer doesn't go online and buys 1 or 10 motors.

It has an acquisition department. In fact, one could argue that's the most important part of the car manufacturer.

They negotiate hard. See if they care that you're making one tenth of the profit you'd make if you sold the motors online. They're buying a million over the next five years, and you're not the only one who can build motors.

So, you can be absolutely certain that the price you see online has nothing to do with the price a car manufacturer would pay for the exact same part.

> But motors of the same power for hobby radio-control cars and aircraft are about a quarter the cost, and a quarter the linear size (so 1/64th the volume and mass).

Well, I don't know that cheap car, but I can promise you that the electric cars I've driven in and been driven in have 50 to 100 kW in power, not less than 1... so something's wrong here.

Also, at the same required power, torque and speed, it's certain that an automotive-grade motor would simply have to be way, way more reliable than a hobbyist motor - you really don't want to be the car manufacturer where motors suddenly burn out at 160 km/h and send your passengers without control over their car into the next obstacle.

"Automotive-qualified" is a standard that electronic parts manufacturers put on more expensive parts, because guess what, car manufacturers negotiate hard, but they have strict guidelines how many failures per million devices they can accept. How many self-built drone hobbyists do you think there are? In a wild estimate, that's less than 100.000 world wide. Are there more than 10 drone motors that have unexpectedly failed? Very likely. So, a car manufacturer couldn't buy these motors, too risky.

Comment: The Changli is very small, very cheap and very slow.  Nothing like most electric cars.  Perhaps a step up from a Sinclair C5, though.

Comment: @SimonB that changes exactly nothing about my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Power is not the only parameter of the engine. It also matters

- How fast does it need to spin to deliver this power? Slow and strong engines need more windings than weaker yet fast (power is the same).
- How well can it move from place a standing car? The engine you address is a propeller engine for a model aircraft.
- How much cooling is required? An open aircraft engine is easier to cool.
- For how long can it work fully loaded? For a model aircraft, it may be ok to replace the engine after maybe days of heavy flying if not earlier. Even cheap car is expected to last much longer.

This may explain the differences in size, complexity and price. Also, 1 hp is a surprisingly weak engine even for a small motorbike.

Answer (score 0):

> *Power is power*

Yes, it is, and you'll find that an 800W cheap motor is more or less the same size as an expensive 800W motor.
The expensive one will usually be a little larger, and that's largely due to design choices that **make it last longer.**  Heat kills motor windings and bearings.

So the question is **how long do you want it to last?**

Some places make special motors that are designed to last 10 minutes. This allows them to make them smaller than other motors that would be designed to last years.

I don't think I would like a car motor to only last 10 minutes!  So it would need to be much larger, so it can handle the run time, heat, torque etc.

Oh yeah, and how fast do you want said car to drive?  I drive my Leaf at 70MPH, on the freeway, which takes about 20kW to maintain. And significantly more to accelerate to that speed in a timely manner so as not to cause a collision!